# How to execute automatic click event of ol.Control.Toggle button

Tags: openlayers, events, ol-ext, button

I'm using a button in Openlayers ol-ext [ol.control.toggle](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.control.Toggle.html#toggle__anchor)

In a certain event, I set this button as active, however, it does not execute the click event.

> Blockquote
> button_draw_select.setActive(true)

How can I change the code beyond showing the active button, auto-run or click event?

```
var button_draw_select = new ol.control.Toggle({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-hand-pointer-o"></i>',
    className: "select",
    title: "Select draw'",
    interaction: new ol.interaction.Select({
        layers: [vector_layer],
        hitTolerance: 2,
    }),
    onToggle: function(active) {
        alert("Select is "+(active?"activated":"deactivated")); 
        if (active === false) button_draw_select.getInteraction().getFeatures().clear()
        
    }
});
```

Comment: By "execute automatic click event" you mean executing `onToggle` function?

Comment: or do you want to simulate a user click on the button? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: So, I want to execute the onToggle function (as if I had clicked and activated the button), from another button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `toogle` option function, you can use control `change:active` event to detect and process the active state change.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var button_draw_select = new ol.control.Toggle({
  html: '<i class="fa fa-hand-pointer-o"></i>',
  className: "select",
  title: "Select draw'",
  interaction: new ol.interaction.Select({
    layers: [vector_layer],
    hitTolerance: 2,
  })
});
  
button_draw_select.on('change:active', function(evt) {
  alert("Select is "+(evt.active?"activated":"deactivated")); 
  if (evt.active === false) button_draw_select.getInteraction().getFeatures().clear()     
}
```

Comment: I changed the `button_draw_select` code by adding an alert to show in `onToggle` and still,
 when I test the code `if (!button_draw_select.getActive()) {
  button_draw_select.toggle();
}` the alert message is not below

Comment: Your are right. I just assumed `.toggle()` method works, but didn't test it. See modified answer, this time it's tested.

Comment: Thank you, I got what I needed to do, with your code example, changing to the `change:active function`